# Microsoft Band UV sensor data unfamiliar

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, microsoft-band

I'm using Microsoft Band of development on Windows Phone 8.1. Trying to figure out he full capability of the UV sensor. I found few examples, that find the UV level. They show that an **enum** can be used:

```
namespace Microsoft.Band.Sensors
{
  public enum UVIndexLevel
  {
    None = 0,
    Low = 1,
    Medium = 2,
    High = 3,
    VeryHigh = 4,
  }
}
```

Would also want to know, what's the scale of these enums. As I know there's like 0 to 11+ levels of UI. What ranges are those enums?

I'm basically **using line of code**:

```
  {
  bandClient.SensorManager.UV.ReadingChanged += Ultraviolet_ReadingChanged;
  await bandClient.SensorManager.UV.StartReadingsAsync();

  *Later on code*

  await bandClient.SensorManager.UV.StopReadingsAsync();
  bandClient.SensorManager.UV.ReadingChanged -= Ultraviolet_ReadingChanged;
  }
```

The **async method**:

```
async void Ultraviolet_ReadingChanged(object sender, BandSensorReadingEventArgs<IBandUVReading> e)
        {
          IBandUVReading ultra = e.SensorReading;
          UVIndexLevel potatoUV = ultra.IndexLevel;
        }
```

But for some reason, I don't get Indexes most of the time. I sometimes get readings around 8 million to 10 million (or thousands) when in direct sunlight. Values are in "int" (Though sometimes gives the enums).
I am interested, on how I can measure it. Also, exactly what UV is it reading? I know there are many kinds of UV exposures. But how can I use this data?
If it's a range, then maybe I can put a range value, but I need to somehow sample it, what UV Index it has and give that information to the user. And use the index in later calculations.

**ALSO...**
I happened to fall on a bug. While testing the UV, when I was standing in direct light, the reading did not display. Only once I moved to another UV level, it changed (But never back to the first one). But seems like the first reading either does not change (As method is "readingchanged") or is the default location. However much sense this makes. Is there a way to call out the reading on button click?

If need be, I can search the examples I used, for mode depth of the code. But most of it is here.

Answer (score 1):

A new Band SDK will be available soon and will fix the UV sensor data not correctly returned. Stay tune!

Comment: yes... Sorry, starting to use stackoverflow and not yet familiar with every conventions.

Answer (score 0):

This sensor is a bit different than the others. It does require the user to do the action to acquire the data and then the data can be gathered.
Here is a code which is working on a WP8.1 with a Band.

```
    DateTime start;

    private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            this.viewModel.StatusMessage = "Connecting to Band";
            // Get the list of Microsoft Bands paired to the phone.
            IBandInfo[] pairedBands = await BandClientManager.Instance.GetBandsAsync();
            if (pairedBands.Length < 1)
            {
                this.viewModel.StatusMessage = "This sample app requires a Microsoft Band paired to your phone. Also make sure that you have the latest firmware installed on your Band, as provided by the latest Microsoft Health app.";
                return;
            }

            // Connect to Microsoft Band.
            using (IBandClient bandClient = await BandClientManager.Instance.ConnectAsync(pairedBands[0]))
            {
                start = DateTime.Now;
                this.viewModel.StatusMessage = "Reading ultraviolet sensor";
                // Subscribe to Ultraviolet data.
                bandClient.SensorManager.UV.ReadingChanged += UV_ReadingChanged;
                await bandClient.SensorManager.UV.StartReadingsAsync();

                // Receive Accelerometer data for a while.
                await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));
                await bandClient.SensorManager.UV.StopReadingsAsync();
                bandClient.SensorManager.UV.ReadingChanged -= UV_ReadingChanged;
            }
            this.viewModel.StatusMessage = "Done";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            this.viewModel.StatusMessage = ex.ToString();
        }
    }

    void UV_ReadingChanged(object sender, Microsoft.Band.Sensors.BandSensorReadingEventArgs<Microsoft.Band.Sensors.IBandUVReading> e)
    {
        var span = (DateTime.Now - start).TotalSeconds;
        IBandUVReading ultra = e.SensorReading;
        string text = string.Format("Ultraviolet = {0}\nTime Stamp = {1}\nTime Span = {2}\n", ultra.IndexLevel, ultra.Timestamp, span);
        Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () => { this.viewModel.StatusMessage = text; }).AsTask();
        start = DateTime.Now;
    }
```

Comment: This code is basically the same to mine. It gives "None" is string when indoors, which is correct. But outdoors, I had clouds and it said something around 196000 +.